# ONNX Runtime and CWaitCursor on Windows

Tags: visual-c++, onnxruntime

I'm running a lengthy algorithm on Windows 10, written in MS Visual C++.   A portion of the algorithm is inferencing an ONNX model using ORT.  I want to spin the wait cursor so the user knows the algorithm is running and not done yet.  It spins except for the part of the algorithm that is ORT inferencing the ONNX model.  I cannot figure out how to have the wait cursor spin during an ORT inferencing.  Got an idea?  Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what you're doing. Do you continue to process window messages during that time or has your application been marked as not responsing?

Comment: Its not getting the "Not Responding" message.   I have tried putting in a periodic ping of the message loop to ensure that doesn't happen.

Comment: I do:   
CWaitCursor wc;
and later
wc.Restore();   // as needed

Comment: Interesting that this popped up today. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20221026-00/?p=107325 If your message loop is still running then you'll have to ensure that `WM_SETCURSOR` doesn't overwrite the hourglass.